# What HyperLink has been clicked in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I am making an asp.net web application which has to play videos. In my start page I have a hyperlink for each video. All the hyperlinks are identical, except their names. This Means they all link to the same page. Im interrested in knowing wether there is an option to know which hyperlink was clicked. I would like to retrieve the name of the hyperlink.

My code for generating the hyperlinks looks as follows:

```
foreach (FileInfo i in corFiles)
    {
        HyperLink t = new HyperLink();
        t.Text = i.Name;
        t.NavigateUrl = "page.aspx";
        CorrectArray.Add(t);
    }
    return CorrectArray;
```

The text of the hyperlink is Unique to a video, which Means I can change the src destination of the video to play based on the text name. So the question goes as follows. Are there any way of retrieving the text name of the hyperlink when it is clicked by the user?

I hope you can help! Thanks in advance.

Regards
Magnus

Comment: Aren't you setting an ID for each of them?

Comment: You can save cookies on user machine, as soon as user clicks on any hyperlink

Comment: @MelanciaUK. No I am not setting an ID for each of them, as there are going to be 100+ and their names will be Unique so they kind of Work as an ID. 

But if it makes it easier I could give them ids? im assuming numbers would be sufficient?

Comment: I was just wondering if their IDs would be the same as their Names, because on the CodeBehind you can easily access the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a link buttons instead of hyper links, if you want to make a post back to the same page.

```
foreach (FileInfo i in corFiles)
{
   LinkButton t = new LinkButton();
   t.Text = i.Name;
   t.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicClick);
   t.CommandName = i.Name;
   CorrectArray.Add(t);
}

void DynamicCommand(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
     // using e.CommandName and e.CommandArgument you can differentiate the hyperlinks
}
```

Comment: But doing this would include me having to make a new page for each hyperlink ? Or am I completely off ?

Comment: @M.frank -No need to create new pages use the same page url with a query string. More over you don't need hyperlink, you can use Link buttons and handle the click event for the link buttons and in the click event you can know which button has been clicked.

Comment: @M.frank - Glad to have helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question,
you have to add the name attribute in the hyperlink tag and get its values in the code behind by fetching names

Comment: Say I have like 100 different hyperlinks. Instead of making each hyperlink link to an individual page. I would like them to link to the same page, but depending on the hyperlink clicked that same page will show a different video.

So I need a way of know which hyperlink the user clicks. Now since the name is Unique for each video, my thought was that I could somehow retrieve that name when the user clicks the hyperlink then I could dynamically change what video the new page was going to show.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Your application is it Asp.net mvc? if it is the case you put the name of the video in a input type hidden and make its name for example `<input type="hidden" name="video" />` and you post it to controller in the click into the link.In controller you get its value like this `string video = Request.Params['video']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery that is integrated into .NET to get the text of the hyperlink upon it is clicked by the user. To be able to access the Hyperlink's text from Javascript simply add it to a custon tag inside the link to have something like this `<a href="page.aspx" htext="hyperlink text">`. As the hyperlink html is generated from .NET server side code you have to generate this custom tag from the .NET server side context.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Querystring?

```
 t.NavigateUrl = "page.aspx?video=<someid>"
```

and in the page you parse the querystring to show the correct video?